# Extracting number out of URL (string)

Tags: jquery

I already know how to extract a number from url `asdf/asdasd.gsdfg-sdfg-asdasd=34234` like this, but what if my URL looks like this `/blaah/sdfggsdfgdsfg-13998.html.html?editcode=814228c1aa`
and number i need to extract is this -> `13998` ?

Comment: Regexp would be the answer, then.

Comment: use `(\d+)` to isolate the number assuming you know how to use rexexp

Comment: `var num = /blaah/sdfggsdfgdsfg-13998.html.html?editcode=814228c1aa.split(".html")[0].split("-")[1];`

Comment: << already know how to extract a number from url >> so,what are you using and where are you stuck then?

Answer (score 0):

```
"/blaah/sdfggsdfgdsfg-13998.html.html?editcode=814228c1aa".match(/-(\d+)\./)[1]
//                                                                ^^^^^^^^ regex
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the situation. If you got regular data that follows a specific, rather simple pattern. You are safe to use functions as split()  / substring() etc.

It would, however, be more sufficient to use a regular expression (regexp), which gives you more flexibility and a more fail-safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way, getting the url from the browser and then match the number:

```
var number = window.location.href.toString().match(/-(\d+)\./)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with `RegExp` you could extract your number easily.
See here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufihax/3/edit).

Hope it helps.